# DestroyFailed Exception Thrown On Just Created Key

Tags: java, scala, jce

Why does this blow up when I have clearly created the key, it's in memory, and therefore should be accessible?

```scala
scala> import javax.crypto.{KeyGenerator, SecretKey}
import javax.crypto.{KeyGenerator, SecretKey}

scala> val keyGen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES")
val keyGen: javax.crypto.KeyGenerator = javax.crypto.KeyGenerator@3a72e2e8

scala> keyGen.init(128)

scala> val key = keyGen.generateKey
val key: javax.crypto.SecretKey = javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec@fffe83f5

scala> key.destroy
javax.security.auth.DestroyFailedException
  at javax.security.auth.Destroyable.destroy(Destroyable.java:53)
  ... 33 elided
```

Using Java 15.

Answer (score 1):

The **SecretKey** that is returned / generated **though** implementing the `Destroyable` interface, does not override the default implementation of the `destroy()` method in the `Destroyable` interface.

This implies that the default destroy() method in the Destroyable interface is invoked and that throws this exception.

```
public default void destroy() throws DestroyFailedException {
    throw new DestroyFailedException();
}
```

This is at line Destroyable:53.

As of now, there does not seem to be a way of cleaning out the secret key from memory. One possible way would be to use reflection to make the byte[] array for the key to be cleaned out in memory by overwriting it.

Comment: WTF - the implementation is to throw an exception ?!

Comment: The default method in the interface throws the exception. The class SecretKeySpec implements SecretKey which implements Destroyable.